# No se muestra información de ficheros en C

Tags: c, linux

Estoy haciendo un programa que simule el comportaiento del comando  ls -l en Linux, pero mi problema es que cuando uso el directorio actual me muestra los fichero y su inforación, pero cuando lo hago desde otro directorio me dice que no se puede abrir  dicho fichero.

Mi código

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void procesar_fichero(char *nombre_fichero);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
struct dirent *info_fichero;
char *nombre_dir;
DIR *dir;

switch(argc)
{
    case 1: nombre_dir = ".";
    break;

    case 2: nombre_dir = argv[1];
    break;

    default:printf("Modo de uso: %s <path>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}


if(!(dir = opendir(nombre_dir)))
{
    printf("Error al abrir el directorio '%s'.\n", nombre_dir);
    printf("No existe el directorio o ruta escrita mal\n");

    return 1;   
}

printf("nombre_fichero\tPermisos\tPropietario\tGrupo\tNodo-i\n");
while(info_fichero = readdir(dir))
    if((strcmp(info_fichero->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(info_fichero->d_name, "..") != 0))
        procesar_fichero(info_fichero->d_name);

closedir(dir);
return 0;
}

 void procesar_fichero(char *nombre_fichero)
 {
struct stat *atributos_fichero = (struct stat *)malloc(sizeof(struct stat));

if(stat(nombre_fichero, atributos_fichero) == -1)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("%s\t", nombre_fichero);
printf("%ld\n", (long)atributos_fichero->st_ino);
printf("\n");

}
```

[image: Aquí todo normal y muestra el fichero y su nodo-i]

[image: Aquí es cuando falla si paso otro directorio]

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que el programa tenga privilegios de acceso al nuevo directorio? En cualquier caso la propia [documentación](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) dice que en caso de devolver -1 consultes `errno` para más detalles.

Comment: Solo viendo la imagen del error, sin mirar tu código: ¿ compruebas que el nombre del directorio no termine en `'/'` ?

Comment: Igual puede ser el erro del '/' pero no sabía que tenía mucha importancia.

Comment: Vistos los resultados, parece que si la tiene ;-)

Comment: Gracs por tu respuesta. Acabo de analizar mi código y parece ser que no tomaba en cuenta la ruta completa del directorio, aunque no entiendo por qué, si se supone que opendir()  y  readdir()  procesan una ruta entera ¿? Eso si no me queda claro aún.

Comment: ¿ Que entiendes por `una ruta entera` ? ¿ Un ruta que termina en `/` ? ¿ No será que la _shell_ u otros programas tienen en cuenta esa posibilidad y la procesan ellos mismos ?

Comment: De todas formas, si han conseguido solucionar tu problema, te invito a que te *auto-respondas* para ayudar a posibles futuros usuarios con el mismo *inconveniente*. Abajo del todo, hay un *checkbox* para `responder tu propia pregunta`. Deberías usarlo.

Comment: Vale. Gracias xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré el error investigando y viendo códigos de terceros y la solución es la siguiente:

Ya que al parecer no tomaba cuentas más que el directorio actual, es decir, no tomaba la ruta absoluta entera (incluyendo el slash `/`) agregué estas líneas que encontré en otro código para probar y !ta tan! funcionó

```
tmp=strlen(ruta);
nombrecompleto=malloc(tmp+strlen(ent->d_name)+2); /* Sumamos 2, por el \0 y 
la barra de directorios (/) no sabemos si falta */
if (ruta[tmp-1]=='/')
    sprintf(nombrecompleto,"%s%s", ruta, ent->d_name);
else
    sprintf(nombrecompleto,"%s/%s", ruta, ent->d_name);
```